# Setting up Zend Loader License path in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-loader

I'm trying to set up Zend Loader but I need to set up

```
zend_loader.license_path=
```

in the php.ini. Sadly my server provider doesn't allow the editing of the php.ini, I'm trying to set it up in my .htaccess file. I tried :

```
php_value zend_loader.license_path /licensefiles/polski.zl
```

but it doesn't work. Using

```
php_value zend_loader.license_path=/licensefiles/polski.zl
```

gives me a 500 internal error

Any ideas how I could get it to work ?

Answer (score 1):

Your server provider may also be preventing you from setting these kinds of values via htaccess files.

Try also putting the path in quotes:

```
php_value zend_loader.license_path "/licensefiles/polski.zl"
```

Once you have set the value, run the phpinfo() function and verify that it's definitely not being picked up.  If not, try and change other php settings via the same method and see if those are/aren't being picked up.

Even though your server provider may block setting of values via htaccess they may provide another way for you to set parameters like this.  For example, some server providers allow you to drop in a local "php.ini" file into your hosting directory which will be picked up and processed.  Check with them.

Comment: I asked my provider and they said that editing the php.ini is not avaible but I can edit it through .htaccess. I can change the zend_loader.obfuscation_level_support through .htaccess with php_value zend_loader.obfuscation_level_support 3 and it shows that it changed in my phpinfo.php. But 
php_value zend_loader.license_path /licensefiles/ninja.zl always shows with License Path no value. I tried putting it in quotes and a lot of other shenanigans but nothing works thus far.

Comment: I did some research for you and it appears that setting cant be set at runtime.  The manual states "The location of the license file must be written into the php.ini file" (http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Guard/content/license_file_location.htm).  This might imply that it is similar to a PHP_INI_SYSTEM setting in php (http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php).  You might be out of luck in that the only way to configure this item is directly in php.ini itself.

Comment: That's what I can deduce from reading the Zend documentation.  The best way would be to verify this with Zend themselves either via a support ticket or through forums.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! There are already a lot similar questions asked but most of them are unanswered. I found this thread a few days ago but I don't understand the answer of the Zend Global Support and sadly the OP didn't update the forum post with a solution. Here's the link: http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=57&t=112603 I'm messaging my host and maybe they'll allow me to edit the php.ini